# Returing structure values back to main() from function()

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, structure

Need some help again. The user is inputting some values in the docreate() function and I need these values back in the main function to print them. I have tried but unable to achieve the goal. I just one characteristic of the drone (name) for now for printing when the user enters 2 in the main code. The code is below:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct drone_t{
    char name[30];
    float top_s;
    float acc;
};

struct do_create(int dronesCreated);

#define MAXDRONES 3

int main()
{
    struct drone_t drone; 
    int dronesCreated = 0;
    int i;
    char namee;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("1. Create Drone\n2. Calculate Time\n3. Exit\n");
        scanf("%d", &i);
        if (i == 1)
        {
            if(dronesCreated<=MAXDRONES-1)
            {
                dronesCreated++;
                do_create(dronesCreated);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("error: cannot create more drones\n");
            }
        }
        else if (i == 2)
        {
            printf("%s", drone[dronesCreated].name);
        }
        else if (i == 3)
        {
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("error: select an option between 1 and 3\n");
        }
    }
}

void do_create(int dronesCreated)
{

    struct drone_t drone[dronesCreated];
    printf("What is the name of the drone?\n");
    scanf("%s", drone[dronesCreated].name);
    printf("What is the top speed of the drone? (kmph)\n");
    scanf("%f", &drone[dronesCreated].top_s);
    printf("What is the acceleration of the drone? (mpsps)\n");
    scanf("%f", &drone[dronesCreated].acc);
    return drone.name;
}
```

Comment: `struct do_create(int dronesCreated);` - is not a valid declaration of anything.

Comment: it was void do_create (int dronesCreated); previously. I changed it to move the values but its not working anyways.

Comment: The array must be defined in `main`. If the return type of the function is `void`, it must not return a value.

Comment: I am having difficult in that, can you please provide a line or an example on how to do that?

Comment: sample [code](https://ideone.com/ybDTGM)

Comment: Note that there is also a bug in that you declare `struct drone_t drone[dronesCreated];` and then reference `drone[dronesCreated]`.  Arrays are numbered from 0, so the final array instance is `drone[dronesCreated - 1]`.  (This code is still quite wrong for several reasons, not least of which is that you are returning a stack variable from a function, which is invalid once the function returns.  As BLUEPIXY says, you must define the array in main if you want to use it in main.  Either that or malloc() in do_create(), or declare as static)

Answer (score 0):

Your code has few errors, fixing them as follow may give you the desired results you are looking for:

1. `struct do_create(int dronesCreated);` is an invalid declaration and it should be `void do_create(int dronesCreated);`
2. you are using drone variable in main as an array but it was declared as drone_t struct, so it should be declared as an array as following: `struct drone_t drone[MAXDRONES];`
3. `char namee;` is never used and either should be removed or should be used
4. arrays in C are 0 indexed, but `dronesCreated` index was initialized to 0 and incremented by 1 in the first if statement, so it will start from 1 instead of 0. Therefore, you have either to initialized it with -1 and when incremented by 1 inside the if statement it then will start from index 0, or you have to incremented it after invoking the do_create
5. `do_create` is declared as void but you are trying to return some value (char* in your case), so you may change it to return `struct drone_t`
6. inside `do_create` you redefine `struct drone_t drone[dronesCreated]` which was defined in main, note that `drone` variable in `do_create` will be the `drone` defined in the clsoest scope, which is the local variable and modifying it will not affect the one defined in main. So, either you have to define it as global variable, to pass it to `do_create` as a parameter, or to make `do_create` return new `struct drone_t` to main and in main to assign it in `drone` array.